# Select specific columns for Linq group by

Tags: .net, linq, listview, group-by

I have a nested ListView. Kinda like this one:
http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/01/building_a_grouping_grid_with.html

And the following Linq query:

```
var query = (from c in context.customer_order
             where c.id > 8000
             group c by c.person_id into cgroup
             select new { cgroup.Key, Orders = cgroup });
```

I only want to load a few specific columns into the cgroup item.
Just like you normally do with the "select" statement in SQL.
Is that possible? I have a blob in the table and it takes ages to load if it is included.

Comment: Do you want to load only a set of columns into the Orders Property of the final result? If so then you may try building anonymous type with the required columns instead of keeping whole object into the Orders property of the end result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var query = (from c in context.customer_order
             where c.id > 8000
             group c by c.person_id into cgroup
             select new { cgroup.Key, Orders =
                    from item in cgroup
                    select new { item.Foo, item.Bar }
             });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var query = (from c in context.customer_order
             where c.id > 8000
             group c.Column by c.person_id into cgroup
             select new { cgroup.Key, Orders = cgroup });
```

Or if you need a few column **s**:

```
var query = (from c in context.customer_order
             where c.id > 8000
             group new { c.Column1, c.Column2 } by c.person_id into cgroup
             select new { cgroup.Key, Orders = cgroup });
```